# Automating database creation using an Azure Powershell Runbook

Tags: powershell, azure, automation

I am attempting to automate the creation of a database server and database using an Azure powershell runbook.

I have managed to create the server ok, but when I then try to connect to it to create the database and user, I hit firewall issues.
I cannot find a way to get the IP address of the runbook so I can add a firewall exclusion.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you create the server add the firewall rule that allows Azure services access to it.

```
New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName [your_server_name] -AllowAllAzureServices
```